# Python quiz difficulty function

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm new to Python and am really struggling to create a function for my quiz: I have created a while loop to offer different levels to the quiz player before they receive any questions.  The while loop works on its own, but when i try to turn it into a function, the level variable stops working (returning only empty brackets outside of the code).

This is the while loop:

```
request_count = 0

level = ()

global_string_list = ()

while request_count < 1:
    print user_level_options

    level_request = raw_input("> ")

    if level_request == "1":
        level = string_1
        global_string_list  = string_1_list

    if level_request == "2":
        level = string_2
        global_string_list  = string_2_list

    if level_request == "3":
        level = string_3
        global_string_list  = string_3_list

    if level_request == False:
        print "Please try again."

    request_count = request_count + 1
```

Could anybody please give me pointers on how to turn this into a function please?
Thank you!!

Comment: can you show your attempt at turning it into a function?

Comment: out of curiosity: what is the purpose of initialising `level` with an empty tuple if you then assign a string to it?

Answer (score 0):

The `level` variable returns empty brackets because the `level` within the function is a *local* variable; completely different from the `level` you declared outside the function, which is outside the function's scope. This outside variable was hidden behind the local `level` variable, so all your assignments within the function were made to the local `level` and did not affect the `level` on the outside at all.

You have to either declare `level` as a `global` variable explicitly (generally considered bad practice) or you return your local `level` from the function. So perform all the changes you want in your function and then use the return statement like this:

```
def user_select():  # your function
    #......your code goes here
    return level

level = user_select() # the level variable within your function is now in this variable
```

Answer (score 0):

> I try to give you a jump start. But I won't give you the final solution.

In general, to make a function meaningful, you have to know why you need it.

I give you some example of the benefit using function.

### Removal of repetitive code. (DRY, don't repeat yourself)

Identify a Pattern, and extract into a separate function. In your example, the repeating behavior can be seen near the condition inside the loop. (right after the `raw_input` function).

That is: `if level_request == <something> then do <some-work>`.

Thus, one improvement could be:

```
def updateLevel(level_request):
    # Think about how you can determine the level without if-else
    level = <?level?>
    global_string_list  = <?global_level|level?>
```

such that you only need to call:

```
while request_count < 1:
    print user_level_options
    level_request = raw_input("> ")
    updateLevel(level_request)

    if level_request == False:
        print "Please try again."

    request_count = request_count + 1
```

### [Abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_(computer_science))

This is a very important topic in Computer Science and General Programming. You have to understand more to be able to appreciate the importance of abstraction.

E.g.

```
def askLevel():
    print(user_level_options)
    return raw_input("> ")

def displayError():
    print("Please try again")

def incrementRequestCounter():
    request_count += 1
```

such that you just need to call:

```
while request_count < 1:
    level_request = askLevel()
    updateLevel(level_request)
    if level_request == False:
        displayError()
    incrementRequestCounter()
```

> Note: in strict functional programming, function is a mapping of (input)->(output). And the function does not modify any global state (immutability). And all function must return a value. But in practice, we normally use a procedure instead. (procedure is a sequence of instruction). And `def` in python is both procedure and function.